# How can I correct my Time Series LSTM RNN for Binary Classification favoring Class 0?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm, tensorflow2.0, data-processing

I am attempting to predict a binary outcome based on 15 continuous sequences (except one which isn't a continuous line, but still a sequence). The dataset contains 933k datapoints for all 15 features Despite my efforts, the model keeps spewing out 0, the favored class. The actual split between the classes in real life for the past 3 years is ~45.09% for 0 and ~54.91% for 1. This is reflected in my dataset, making it skewed. Generally, you can undersample or oversample to create a perfect 50/50 split, but with LSTM, you require a continuous lagged dataset (or so I assume from everything I have read about it, but does this only apply for sequence to sequence RNNs, and not for binary classification?) so adding or removing samples randomly won't work.One thing to note is that this model has not been trained significantly yet as I have been trying to figure out what could be the underlying issue, but from what i have seen, training it doesn't seem to improve it, only worsen it, making it favor 0 even more. This is proven with the recall falling for every epoch. The loss, accuracy and precision does slightly increase though, but likely due to the skewed dataset, making it approach the 54%.

So what I am asking is, how can I allow the algorithm to learn from the dataset, and not adapt to its bias?

Here's the model:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
X_train, y_train, X_cv, y_cv, X_test, y_test, init_bias = data_formatting.transform(data=data)
output_bias = tf.keras.initializers.Constant(init_bias)
model1 = Sequential([
    InputLayer(batch_input_shape=(64, 60, 15)),
    LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True, stateful=True),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True, stateful=True),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    LSTM(units=64, stateful=True),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    Dense(units=32, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid', bias_initializer=output_bias)
])

model1.summary()

cp = ModelCheckpoint('Model_NewF_3/', save_best_only=True)

model1.compile(loss=BinaryCrossentropy(), optimizer=AdamW(learning_rate=0.000001), metrics=['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.Precision(), tf.keras.metrics.Recall()])

model1.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_cv, y_cv), epochs=10, batch_size=64, callbacks=[cp])
```

P.S. the data_formatting module is my preprocessing

Here's my train set confusion matrix:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dE0G5.png)

And here's my test set confusion matrix:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMHZH.png)

I have tried increasing and decreasing the learning rate, simplifying the model, enlarging the model, adding bias_initializer, dropout, different timelags. I have tried removing the "flats" in my dataset, I've tried overfitting it to a small dataset (which after 1000 epochs yielded 55%-75% accuracy on the final epochs, so may there be a problem with its learnability? I've been expecting to predict around 55%+ on test sets and validation sets with somewhere around an equal split between the classes (40-60, 50-50, 60-40, somewhere around there)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

Refer to the Tensorflow [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data)  that details exactly how to do this. The following is directly from that source but please use the link for more details, if needed.

1. Calculate pos and neg class weights and put into a dictionary.

```
# Scaling by total/2 helps keep the loss to a similar magnitude.
# The sum of the weights of all examples stays the same.
weight_for_0 = (1 / neg) * (total / 2.0)
weight_for_1 = (1 / pos) * (total / 2.0)

class_weight = {0: weight_for_0, 1: weight_for_1}

print('Weight for class 0: {:.2f}'.format(weight_for_0))
print('Weight for class 1: {:.2f}'.format(weight_for_1))


Weight for class 0: 0.50
Weight for class 1: 289.44
```

2. Pass to the model when calling fit.

```
weighted_model = make_model()
weighted_model.load_weights(initial_weights)

weighted_history = weighted_model.fit(
    train_features,
    train_labels,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    callbacks=[early_stopping],
    validation_data=(val_features, val_labels),
    # The class weights go here
    class_weight=class_weight)
```